# fetch data flutter api

Tags: flutter, api

I want to get data from API and I tried the link in postman and its working here it is: [ { "Id": "14", "title": "Facebook vs instagram?", }, { "Id": "15", "title": "Facebook vs instagram?", }, { "Id": "16", "title": "Facebook vs instagram?", }, ]

but when I am trying to do a map this error appears : error catch type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast.

Here is my code : This error appears in this file and print(recieved) print the same data as postman but the problem in map httpservice.dart:
`

```
class HttpService {
  final String postsURL =
      "";

  Future<List<Post>> getPosts() async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse(postsURL));

    

    request.headers.addAll(headers);
    List<Post> Posts = [];
    try {
      http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
final result = jsonDecode(response.body) as List; 

        List<Post> posts = result
            .map(
              (dynamic item) => Post.fromJson(item),
            )
            .toList();

        return Posts;
      }
}
```

`
post_model.dart :

`

class Post {

```
  final String Id;
  final String title;

  Post({
    required this.Id,
    required this.title,
  });

  factory Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Post(
       Id: json['Id'] as String,
      title: json['title'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

` post.dart :

```
class PostsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final HttpService httpService = HttpService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Posts"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: httpService.getPosts(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Post>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Post> posts = snapshot.data!;
            return ListView(
              children: posts
                  .map(
                    (Post post) => ListTile(
                      title: Text(post.title),
                      subtitle: Text("${post.Id}"),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            );
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please print response.body? before convert it with jsonDecode.

Comment: before : [{"Id":"27","title":"instagram?"}]

Answer (score 0):

The http package gives the data as json in default. You are again trying to decode the decode the response body but the jsonDecode expects string type as parameter.

Simply, all you need to do is remove the jsonDecode

From

```
final result = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
```

to

```
final result = response.body as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

Comment: when I do that. this error appears in map : The method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'map'

Comment: after I did that, the map under it doesn't work : this List<Post> posts = result
            .map(
              (dynamic item) => Post.fromJson(item),
            )
            .toList();

Comment: just updated the answer. Need to typecast the response

Comment: this error appears : The method 'toList' isn't defined for the type 'Map'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toList'